# Why is this code set removing 2 items from a list but only appending one?

Tags: python-3.x

When calling the draw function I lose two cards from the deck but only one is appended to the players hand. I can't figure out what is happening with the other cards.

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.build()

    # builds the deck with 52 playing cards
    def build(self):
        for suit in ["Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", 'Hearts']:
            for val in range(2, 15):
                if val == 11:
                    self.cards.append(Card(suit, "Jack"))

                elif val == 12:
                    self.cards.append(Card(suit, "Queen"))

                elif val == 13:
                    self.cards.append(Card(suit, "King"))

                elif val == 14:
                    self.cards.append(Card(suit, "Ace"))

                else:
                    self.cards.append(Card(suit, val))

    # method to show all cards in the deck
    def show(self):
        for c in self.cards:
            c.show()

    # shuffles the deck
    def shuffle(self):
        for i in range(len(self.cards) - 1, 0, -1):
            r = random.randint(0, i)
            self.cards[i], self.cards[r] = self.cards[r], self.cards[i]

    # pulls a card from the deck
    def drawCard(self):

        if len(self.cards) == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return self.cards.pop()

class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, val):
        self.suit = suit
        self.val = val

    def show(self):
        print(f"{self.val} of {self.suit}")

class Player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []

    def draw(self, deck):
        if deck.drawCard() == 0:
            print("No cards left in the deck. \n")
        else:
            self.hand.append(deck.drawCard())
            return self
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Player.draw()`, you're calling `deck.drawCard()` twice - once to check if that card is zero, and then again when you append it to your hand.

Instead, add a line at the beginning to save the result of `deck.drawCard()` to a variable - only calling it once - and then, once that variable is assigned, use it twice:

```
def draw(self, deck):
    card = deck.drawCard()
    if card == 0:
        print("No cards left in the deck. \n")
    else:
        self.hand.append(card)
        return self
```

Comment: That worked thank you! I feel really dumb that I missed that lol.